# C struct: what does this mean?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

```
typedef struct{
        unsigned  flanke:1;         
        unsigned  lastState:1;  
        } flanke_t;
```

I do not understand the ":1". Please help me, thx.

Comment: might have been a typo for '='

Comment: have a look here: http://c-faq.com/struct/bitfield0.html

Comment: ":1" means occupies 1 bit, (not the value 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are bit fields: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field. Here you just reserve 1 bit for 'flanke' and one for the 'lastState'. The type has to be unsigned int.

Comment: +1, but this link have some Microsoft specifics, I suggest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is [bit field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) declaration usage. it is used to indicate the number of bits a given structure member will occupy in the structure so its main usage is to pack a structure so that it occupies less memory.